# How can I a make a bunch of custom exceptions to be a non-retry-able exception?

Tags: spring-kafka

I'm using spring boot 2.1.7.RELEASE and spring-kafka 2.2.8.RELEASE.And I'm using @KafkaListener annotation to create a consumer and I'm using all default settings for the consumer.

Now my questions

1. How make a bunch of custom exceptions to be a non-retry-able exception(For example DeserializationException)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ability to classify exceptions to be retryable or not was added to the `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` in version 2.3 (boot 2.2).

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/983

improved by https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/1260

And deserialization exceptions are classified as not retryable by default.

Comment: Thanks for the response. If my interpretation of your explanation is correct, even with spring-kafka 2.2.8.RELEASE, deserialization exceptions are classified as not retryable. Please confirm

Comment: No; it was a new feature added in 2.3; with earlier versions all exceptions were retried; you either need to upgrade or write your own custom error handler with similar logic to the 2.3 version.